# how to launch multiple instance in scale-up policy?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I using cloud formation template to auto scale application but i want to launch two instance with once scale up policy

like when i scale-up my web application along with that my data base instance also be launch with different user data in formation template

any one know about how to launch multiple instance in one launch config. please help me out if any body has already implemented

Answer (score 1):

It's the "adjustment" parameter of the scaling policy call, as-put-scaling-policy, [see the reference](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/AutoScaling/latest/as-qrc.pdf)

1 means scale up one per trigger, 2, scale up two, -2, scale down two, etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i not wont to launch same instance in scale up i wont to scale up two different instance like one instance with tomcate and another with mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  A Scaling Group is a group of the same resources for scaling, and a Launch configuration is a single configuration to launch an instance.

What you *can* do is trigger two policies from the one alarm.  Go down that path.